# jquery countdown, ajax call, remove element error

Tags: jquery, setinterval, countdown, clearinterval

okay so, im working on this site where i have a bunch of different `elements` on one page counting down at the same time, and when they hit 0 , i would like for them to make an `ajax-call`, to remove the timer initiator ,then remove this `li element` timer. now as i said this countdown function is on multiple `elements` so how do i `clear Interval` for this specific `element` ?

There is alot of markup so that you guys can get a more broud view of what im trying to do , for that reason i just fiddled -> http://jsfiddle.net/vKtSB/3/

Answer (score 0):

Well you used this syntax to initiate the interval -

```
MasterObjectINvals['snake'][sid] = setInterval(function(){...});
```

So why couldn't you simply use the same syntax to remove it?

```
var $sid = $("#selectedElement").attr('id');
clearInterval(MasterObjectINvals['snake'][$sid]);
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that that sounds quite disturbing, sorry, no.  I simply don't have time to sift through that much code.  What exactly is the problem that you are facing?  You can't retrieve the ID's of the elements?

Comment: no when it counts down to the time to clear its not removing the elemnt from the page and the countdown isnt stopping, it makes its ajax call perfect.. if i would refresh the page.... then it wouldn't be there, i simply cant get the li to fadeOut and remove becuase the countdown keeps counting

Answer (score 0):

you var sid, is an array... it's not just one ID.

start here: http://jsfiddle.net/vKtSB/5/